# Handlebars helper is not defined.

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have div that displays a content from mysql database. The content is too long so I decided to use Handlebar helpers. Here is my html code:

```
    <div class="row">
    {{#if news}}
        {{#each news}}

            <div class="col-md-4 img-portfolio">
                <a href="/news-details/{{id}}">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-hover small-img" src="/images/news/{{image}}" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/news-details/{{id}}">{{title}}</a>
                </h3>
                <p> {{substr "10" text}} </p>
            </div>
            {{/each}}        
     {{else}}
     <p>No News</p>
{{/if}}
```

The Handlebar Helper is placed in index.js file as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('substr', function(length, context, options) {
  if ( context.length > length ) {
       return context.substring(0, length) + "...";
  } else {
      return context;
   }
});
```

When I run the nodejs server, I receive "Handlebar is not defined" error. I installed express-handlebar package and also declared it on the index.js file as

```
var Handlebar = require('express-handlebars');
```

But it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not a "right" answer but it made the problem to be solved. I used CSS to make it work. Simply I added an ID as "test" for the paragraph tag and assign css in the style.css file as follow:

```
#test {
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* Opera */
text-overflow:    ellipsis;   /* IE, Safari (WebKit) */
overflow:hidden;              /* don't show excess chars */
white-space:nowrap;           /* force single line */
width: 350px;                 /* fixed width */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Handlebars` as variable name instead of `Handlebar`.

Also, official [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers) documentation for helpers suggest do define helpers under `exphbs.create`.

So the code with helper on the server should be like:

```
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars"); // you can use any variable name

var hbs = exphbs.create({
  helpers: {
    substr: function(length, context, options) {
      if (context.length > length) {
        return context.substring(0, length) + "...";
      } else {
        return context;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Like how to do this?

Comment: @Karatay edited the answer to reflect express-handlebars documentation helper registration. For usage, see [Usage section](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#basic-usage) of express-handlebars documentation.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it keeps saying  Missing helper: "substr". I have the last version of express-handlebars and express.

Comment: @Karatay I have tested it on a quick express app and it works for me, are you sure you have view engine configured and all your files end on .hbs (or .handlebars, if you set "view engine" as "handlebars") extension?

Comment: Yes definitely. For some reason, It doesn't work with custom helpers. I used #if and #each w/out any problems. I also used 'code'<p>{{substr '20' text}}</p> in the handlebars file.

Comment: @Karatay I'm a little bit confused right now, does the `substr` helper work for you or not?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. The other built-in helpers like if or each work but custom helpers like substr doesn't.

Comment: @Karatay It renders the `substr` for me, I use [this code (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/atgg/3c458a5678ac0f7f9dbfb5d51e2ba50f) on node server. Having the `index.hbs` file in views folder with the `substr` helper.

Comment: Thank you Adrian for the help but it doesn't work for me. I'll handle the issue with JavaScript and keep investigate.